# Deploying using Setup project with update functionality of ClickOnce

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I want to deploy a wpf client appllication, I need to allow the user to choose a directory for the install, eg. c:\program files\myapp. Unable to do this with clickonce, I need to use a setup project to deploy my app. How can I have the same update functionality as a ClicOnce app in my setup project? ie Have the app check an adddress for update, download only changed parts of the app, and patch the client application.

Comment: Could you explain the reasons why the user needs to be able to choose the install location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to wrap your application inside of another controller application responsible for launching the main app.

This way you can use your wrapper app to check for updates, replace files, and control the running of the main application.

I belive this is the way Firefox does it, and is the reason FF has to restart after doing updates. This is because updater.exe is in controll of  the updating and running of FF its self.

[Here's some information about the something called AppUpdater](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)